# High CPU Usage by sw-engine-fpm Ubuntu

Tags: linux, performance, ubuntu, plesk

i am running a Ubuntu 12.04.05 LTS VServer (6GB Ram, 4VCores).

The Process "sw-engine-fpm" by the user "psaadm" uses up to 22% of CPU Usage all the time.
I am doing nothing in my Plesk. There aren't running any big Requests on the Server.

Panel version: 11.5.30 Update #47 , last updated at July 15, 2014 08:11 PM

Do you have any Ideas what i could try?

Comment: Switch debug and logging at /etc/sw-engine/sw-engine-fpm.conf and check log file /var/log/sw-cp-server/sw-engine.log

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
sudo service sw-engine status
sudo service sw-engine restart
```

That worked for me. I got the same situation by running a query in phymyadmin. By just running the same query I could get repeatedly get the same result. To me it looks like a bug.

You could also try: https://kb.plesk.com/en/112543